# Migration from OpenText to SDL Tridion Sites

Tags: migration

Has anyone tried to migrate templates and content from OpenText to SDL Tridion Sites? Any tool or strategy anyone can share.

Comment: OpenText has a few content management systems and portals. Which one are you looking to migrate from?

Answer (score 3):

It has been a long while since I tried anything like this.

- Templates - very unlikely you would be able to move these. I am assuming a Template here refers to what in Tridion is called a Content Schema?
- Content - Content in Tridion is stored in Components, which are basically XML documents. I would normally create my own tool for this, using the Tridion Core service to read the source and map it to a Tridion Component's fields.

As far as I know, there are no tools pre-built for this, but I could be wrong. It could very well be that Tridion Professional Services or some of our partners have built something for this specific use case...

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks Nuno. Let's see if we can hear back from the community on some of their learnings from migration.